# RecyclerView animation in oval shape

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a recycler view (wheel Shaped) which can show up and down side faded and scrolling effect in oval shape. I am attaching the sample image here too.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Too broad for SO . You can have a look at [This library](https://github.com/jpardogo/FlabbyListView) , This not exactly what you want but you can have a look .

Comment: Also since `RecyclerView` is one of Awesome Widget in android(Very much customizable ) . You can create a custom `Layoutmanager` as per your need. Look in Open source `LayoutManager's` code for reference.

Comment: @ADM Thank you, I will try to customise `LayoutManager`

Comment: I just want to know why people have down voted this question, is this a silly question? Before down voting they should understand what a person trying to ask. It demotivates people to use this community.

Comment: This is not the place to ask how to do something so broad. This site is much better for asked exact, focused questions about specific details. This question does not show that you put much effort into using Google before posting it, and people here prefer that you do your own research before posting questions. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a [Github Link](https://github.com/inmyfree/awsome-3D-listview/blob/master/src/com/sonyericsson/tutorial/list3/MyListView.java).

Though I have to do some changes but yes it worked for me.